# A sentence structure after the preposition - without

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I have found this humorous text passage on the net :

" Well, to be perfectly honest, in my humble opinion, of course without offending anyone who thinks differently from my point of view, but also by looking into this matter in a different perspective and without being condemning of ones` views and by trying to make it objectified, and by considering each and every one's valid opinion, I honestly believe that I completely forgot what I was going to say."

Here is the sentence that troubles me - **" without being condemning of ones`"** views ". Is this sentence similar in meaning to -**" without condemning ones views "**? If there is a measurable difference between these two, if so, then what is the difference ?